# How do I change the background on a bootstrap container

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs, bootstrap-5

So I'm making a ejs login project, style.css:

```css
[theme="bloodRed"] {
    background-color: #ff2424;
    color: #e571e1;
    accent-color: #00ff00;
}
```

register.ejs:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" theme="bloodRed">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Sign up</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="login-box">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h2>Sign up</h2>
                        <form action="register" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>First and Last name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info" style="margin-top: 10px;"> Sign up </button>
                        </form>
                        <p style="margin-top: 15px;">Already have an account?   <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="login">Login here!</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and then this js code connects them:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

but in register.ejs, the text doesnt change, neither does the background, if you go outside the div its red, help?

Comment: Did you try adding CSS to the container class? `.container {
  background-color: red;
  }`

Comment: i want it to be in the `[theme="bloodRed"]` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS follows rules of specificity and cascade.  You're adding your `theme` property to the html element, but the Bootstrap CSS (in the reboot) is overriding it because it's applying a background-color of white on the body and a text `color` of `#212529;`.

Adding your theme property to the `body` tag, will help, but there are lots of other places that will apply text or background colors.  It's better to use the Bootstrap SASS modules and/or custom properties (CSS variables).  The documentation section on [Customization](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/overview/) details how.

Comment: i followed it but how do i change the accent color?

Comment: nevermind i found it